# Serving static HTML in Rails with a layout file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, ruby-on-rails-3.2

What's the best way to serve static HTML documents in Rails with a layout? Obviously I could just keep the HTML files in the `public/` directory, but then I wouldn't be able to apply a layout, or could I? Otherwise I could put the following in `config/routes.rb`:

```
match ':page' => 'static#display', :page => /.+\.html/
```

Does `.+\.html` work so it ends with `.html`? Anyway, assuming it did, I guess I'd have a controller:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  layout 'static_files'
  def display
    render params[:page]
  end
end
```

Assuming that works properly, will Ruby unnecessarily try and parse the HTML file as an ERB file? Is there a better mechanism Rails has for this?

Comment: From what I understand it seems like Rails will parse the `.html` files through `ERB` if the files have the `.html.erb` extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [**high_voltage gem**](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) by Thoughtbot. It's purpose is to include static pages in Rails, and you use any templating language you like. Internally it works similarly to the solutions proposed here.

You can customize the layout file for every single page served by high_voltage as described [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage#override) in the Readme.

Comment: This looks perfect, trying this now.

Answer (score 5):

This [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages.html#sec-static_pages_with_rails) has a pretty good explanation of static pages in rails.

First you can generate the static pages via the rails generator:

```
rails generate controller StaticPages home help --no-test-framework
```

Then you can edit your `config/routes.rb` to look like the following:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  .
  .
  .
end
```

And finally in your `StaticPages` controller you create the `home` and `help` methods.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end
end
```

**UPDATE** - 
[quote source: Ruby on Rails Guides - Section 2.1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

> You’ve heard that Rails promotes “convention over configuration”.
>   Default rendering is an excellent example of this. By default,
>   controllers in Rails automatically render views with names that
>   correspond to valid routes. For example, if you have this code in your
>   BooksController class:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController 
  #empty controller
end
```

And the following in your routes file:

```
resources :books
```

And if you have a view file `app/views/books/index.html.erb`, then Rails will render it even without the methods. This should work for any mapped routes/equivalent views.

Comment: I don't want to create 85 methods in the pages controller for my 85 static html pages. Like my example above, I want a catch-all route going to a single controller action at most.

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller for handling static pages

```
rails generate controller pages
```

Map routes to these actions in routes.rb

```
match '/home' => 'pages#home'
match '/help' => 'pages#help'
match '/contact' => 'pages#contact'
```

Create actions in pages controller

```
def home
CODE
end

def contact
CODE
end

def help
CODE
end
```

By default, rails will look for ACTION.html.erb in the view folder. Create views and voila. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I don't want to create 85 methods in the pages controller for my 85 static html pages. Like my example above, I want a catch-all route going to a single controller action at most.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to create 85 methods in the pages controller for my 85 static HTML pages.

This may seem a little hackish but does exactly what you want:

```
# File: app/controllers/static_controller.rb

class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

Now put something under the correct directory, for example `app/views/static/example.html.erb`, and route to it:

```
get '/example', to: 'static#example'
```

You didn't really define an action named `method_missing`, but something with black magic. There's documentation for this: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing